# I don't see my objects on the Django site

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I try to create Django Build-in API Documentation however I can't add objects to the list on the left. When I open `localhost:8000/docs/` I don't see list of my objects as at the top of [the official Django REST documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.6-announcement/) (in this case snippets and users). Currently I am trying in this way:

urls.py:

```
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls

API_TITLE = 'API title'
API_DESCRIPTION = '..df.'

urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title=API_TITLE, description=API_DESCRIPTION)),
]
```

models.py:

```
class Object1(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    value = models.FloatField()
```

admin.py based on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Admin_site):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Object1
# Register your models here.


admin.site.register(Object1)
```

I also based on [https://docs.djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) and I tried with this admin.py version:

```
class Object1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Object1, Object1Admin)
```

I was using also other versions but I did not get a positive result with them, too. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
I was trying to create ViewSet in my views file and import that in url to define router as Raja Simon suggested:

views.py:

```
from rest_framework import viewset


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

urls.py:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

# Create a router and register our viewsets with it.
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

However I didn't achieve what I wanted to. At this moment my list on Django site looks in this way:
[image]

But I would like to have list of my objects like in this case:
[image]

Comment: Please create viewset and add them to your router. Then you should see that in docs...

Comment: I use only views in my project. Is it possible to use them instead of viewsets?

Comment: I don't think so. See this coreapi tightly coupled with Django RestFramework not with Django though...

Comment: So I have to change my whole source code from `views.py` into viewsets?

Comment: I think that this is the issue https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5003. I have a similar issue.

Comment: @Xepe I don't use schemas (should I?) in my project and I don't have multiple apps.

Comment: May I ask why you don't set up an API like [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/). I mean you need an `APIview` in your views.py. `class yourAPI(APIView):` Thats how I put up my APIs

Comment: @hansTheFranz All my views look in this way `@api_view(['GET','POST', etc.])
@permission_classes([MyPermission])
def Name(request): body of view` I import views to urls.py and call in URL by `views.NameOfView`. Is it a wrong solution? I need an `APIview` to get what I wanted to achieve with my Django documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

To

```
user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

It should probably work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Just create ViewSet in your views file and import that in url to define router

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewset


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

**urls.py**

```
# Create a router and register our viewsets with it.
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
```

Comment: `url(r'^', include(router.urls)),` should be in `urlpatterns`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply yes. It should be in `urlpatterns` list

Comment: There is a problem with `urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)` in urls.py. When I comment it I can't open admin site. On the other hand when it is accessible I get error in `url(r'^', include(router.urls)),` log: `django_1   | django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: "^users\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$" is not a valid regular expression: redefinition of group name 'format' as group 2; was group 1 at position 37`

Comment: Can you include your urls in question?

Comment: It seems to me that problem is not associated with my urls because when I comment all of my urls and I have only `url(r'^', include(router.urls)),` in `urlpatterns` there is the same problem. So it doesn't work with `urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)`.